# Unity: кратчайший доступ к переменной класса

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сабж:

```
  public class MyClass1
    {
           public MyClass2 myClass2 = new MyClass2 ();
    }

    public class MyClass2
    {
        public int myValue = 1;
    }
```

Доступ:

```
MyClass1 myClass1 = new MyClass1();
int needed = myClass1.myClass2.myValue;
```

Вопрос:
Если необходимо часто использовать переменную myClass1.myClass2.myValue (не значение, а именно её, с возможностью изменять),
могу-ли я сократить выражение каким-то образом, чтоб не писать постоянно "myClass1.myClass2.myValue"?

Варианты типа:

```
  int needed = myClass1.myClass2.myValue;
    needed++;
    myClass1.myClass2.myValue = needed;
```

не подходят (действия могут происходить из разных веток кода, всегда нужно текущее значение).

Comment: Возможно, будет удобно использовать [Свойства](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно описать [свойство](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) в `MyClass1`

```
public class MyClass1
{
       public MyClass2 myClass2 = new MyClass2 ();
       public int quickAccess {
           get { return myClass2.Value; }
           set { myClass2.Value = value; }
       }
}
```

Comment: `public MyClass2 quickAccess => myClass2.Value;`. Только наверно не MyClass, а int (если брать пример автора).

Comment: спасибо, поправил